# Is it Necessary to Dispose DataTable, OleDbCommand and OleDbDataAdapter?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado.net, oledb, dispose

I'm fully aware that the OleDbConnection and OleDbDataReader should be disposed when not in use or after using them. I'm thinking, what about the others - DataTable, OleDbCommand, OleDbDataAdapter?

I declare the 3 objects as follows

```
 Dim dbTable as New DataTable
 Dim dbCommand as New OleDbCommand
 Dim dbAdapter as New OleDbDataAdapter
```

Comment: Do you really care, or want to know that much of their implementation? Keep it simple: When a class implements `IDisposable`, Dispose the objects.

Comment: How do I know if they implement IDisposable? I'm pretty new in Visual Basic and not yet familiar with interface.

Comment: The docs, really. A quick check is to see if `.Dispose()` shows up in Intellisense.

Comment: use intelisense. `Object.Dispose()`. and then, you can use `using' keyword. When this keyword is used, it takes care of disposing in `try-catch-finally` . Read MSDN about `using`